# org-mode html publish fails with invalid regex error

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I am using org-mode for generating a static website for my notes. For this, I followed the tutoriala at:

https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html

And this is the relevant part on my .emacs file:

```
;; Org-mode html publish
(require 'ox-publish)
(setq org-publish-project-alist
  '(
    ("org-notes"
        :base-directory "~/org/"
        :base-extension "org"
        :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
        :recursive t
        :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
        :headline-levels 4             ; Just the default for this project.
        :auto-preamble t
    )
    ("org-static"
        :base-directory "~/org/"
        :base-extension "css\\|js\\|php\\|jpg\\|png\\"
        :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
        :recursive t
        :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
    )
    ("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))
))
```

And I used this one for quite some time now. But lately, when I do `M-x org-publish-project` and pick `org-static`, it fails with the error message `Invalid regexp: "Unmatched ( or \\("`. I wonder where is the problem in my config and how this started failing all of a sudden. The project `org-notes` still works fine.

Comment: You should make sure that `debug-on-error` is set (by using `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` or ortherwise) and add the backtrace to the question. My guess is that the `base-extension` regexp should be `"css\\|js\\|php\\|jpg\\|png"` - the final (escaped) backslash looks out of place.

Answer (score 1):

Check the comment from @NickD, regex:

```
:base-extension "css\\|js\\|php\\|jpg\\|png\\"
```

is indeed wrong if we follow the tutorial exactly. I removed the last `\\`. Still, as I said, this was working before. The actual error was that a package named `cl` is not supported by Emacs anymore. For that, I had to see which packages are depending on it and I evaluated following on `*scratch*`:

```
(require 'loadhist)
(file-dependents (feature-file 'cl))
```

and saw that the package `htmlize`, which I use for org publishing was depending on it. The newer versions of this package are updated to work without the `cl` package. So, I had to reinstall `htmlize` basically and things started working again.

Comment: +1 for the way to check dependencies. What version of emacs are you running? I can still find `cl.el` in upstream emacs and it is installed (and found) under `/usr/local/share/emacs/28.0.50/lisp/obsolete/cl.elc`.

Comment: I upgraded to emacs28 and started getting the error related to `cl`. Previously I was using emacs26. Maybe difference is because I am using some Windows builds?